# Kotlin: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.lang.Object)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to create a kotlin database by room
https://github.com/wwweblo/wardrobe
but I have some troubles with it

```
@Dao
interface ClothingItemDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(item: ClothingItem)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM clothing_items ORDER BY name")
    fun getAllClothingItems(): LiveData<List<ClothingItem>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM clothing_items WHERE :tag IN (:tags) ORDER BY name")
    fun getClothingItemsByTag(tag: String, tags: List<String>): LiveData<List<ClothingItem>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM clothing_items ORDER BY name")
    suspend fun getAllClothingItemsSync(): List<ClothingItem>
}
```

error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.lang.Object).
public abstract java.lang.Object getAllClothingItemsSync(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
^

main actitvy will show names to the user of added clothes and have a button to add new.